# How to drop a prefix from hg archive?

Tags: mercurial

I would like to export files from a repository, ignoring changes in the working tree. Furthermore, rather than exporting everything, I would like to see a subset of it. The destination directory might already contain some files and those must be overwritten.

Given:

```
project/some/sub/dir/
```

I would like to export it to:

```
output/dir/
```

In `git`, I can use:

```
git archive --prefix=dir/ HEAD -- some/sub/dir/ | tar -xv -C output
```

What is the equivalent command in `hg`? If I use `hg archive -t files -I some/sub/dir output/`, then I get `output/some/sub/dir`. I could pipe the result through tar, but then I have to manually calculate the prefix that should be dropped:

```
hg archive -t tar -I some/sub/dir/ - |
    tar -xv -C output --strip-components=3
```

(in reality, I have some other tar patterns that should be ignored such as `--exclude='.*'`). Any ideas? This export will be done for three other directories located in the repository.

Current situation:

```
srcdir=some/sub/dir
dstdir=output/dir
# hg archive auto-adds a 'proj-version' prefix. Given the srcdir,
# proj-version/some/sub/dir/X should become dstdir/X, so strip 4 components
prefixlength=$(grep -c / <<<"/${srcdir%%/}/")
hg archive -t tar -I "$srcdir" - |
    tar -xv -C "$dstdir" --strip-components=$prefixlength
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

- `hg archive ... && cd output/some/sub/dir && tar ...` isn't it?
- Build intermediate repo ([Convert Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension)), where `some/sub/dir/` will be root of this repository (understand also sample from [Converting from Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) topic) and get tar'red archive directly from `hg archive` for intermediate repository

Comment: I can already use `tar` with `--strip-components`, but would like to avoid that. I am really not looking for getting a subset of the repo, just the files. Something like `git archive` or `svn export`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn - and what is bad with any of my solutions?! Different ways, the same result

Comment: I was looking for something more elegant. The first `hg archive -t tar ... && cd output/some/sub/dir && tar xv --strip-components` (?) is slightly worse than the current situation. See the simple `git` invocation for what I am aiming at. The second example creates a new repo which seems even more complicated.

Comment: @Lekensteyn - a) 1-st solution have to be used without `--strip-components`: `pwd` is dir of tar-ing, you have flat space of `some/sub/dir/` b) fast convert (for *me*) isn't more complicated - only three short, easy-readable (contrary to Git's syntax, but it's common weakness of Git) commands